# The only cut vertex in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity, eulerian-path

Let a graph $G$ be arbitrarily traversable from a vertex $v$, i.e., any trail in $G$ initiatng from $v$ ultimately results in an Eulerian $v-v$ circuit. Let $v$ be a cut-vertex in $G$. Is it true that $v$ is necessarily the only cut-vertex in $G$?

When $v$ is a cut vertex, it means that $G-v$ must be disconnected. Now, we should prove that for any other verex $v_0$ in $G$, the graph $G-v_0$ is connected. I think we should take two vertices $u$ and $w$ in $G-v_0$ and using a certain trail linking these two with $v$ reach at a path between $u$ and $w$. Am I rightly starting?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: An easier approach: assuming $v_0$ is a cut vertex, can you construct a trail from $v$ that dead-ends without creating a Eulerian circuit?

Comment: @MishaLavrov : Then, the point $v$ lies in a component $C$ of $G-v_0$ so that, due to the connectedness of $C$, a path could be started from $v$ toward any other vertex in $C$. Now, by removing the edges in $G$ incident with $v_0$, one could not link this path with those verices in the  other components. Does this work, or  not?